# Moving from SVN to GIT , best way to copy full repos?

Tags: 12.04, git, rsync, svn

We are changing from SVN to GIT, and I wonder which is the best way to copy the files from one to another server.
For that I would use rsync but I need to know if I can first copy the files and than convert the new folder a git repository or should I first create the repos and copy the files in later?
Or is there no difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best and natural way is cloning repository with git-svn

[git-svn-tutorial](http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

You will need git-svn

```
sudo apt-get install git-svn
```

Now do these commands

```
git svn clone http://mysvnrepo.com/my-project my-project
cd my-project
git remote add origin git@mygitrepo.com:/my-project.git
git push origin master
```

replace my-project with your repo name